# Attaching an image (base64) to input type=“file”

Tags: javascript, html, base64, local-storage

There is a form

```html
<form method="post" action="pixels.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="graphic" style=" font-size:14px;" value="data:image/png;base64,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"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I'm trying to attach an image (`base64`) to `input`, `base64` is taken from another draftsman via `localstorage`, from there it turned out to be set only to `value`.

According to the plan, it should be like this, draw, go to another page, there through `onload` from `localstorage` it is inserted into `input`, and when you click download it should pick up the file (jpg).

Answer (score 0):

you could attack that base64 string to a tag to download 
like

```
<a download="picname.jpg" href="data:image/png;base64,string..">download picture</a>
```

when user clicks download it should download  as picture